# Import from Pervasive Database Files

Tags: pervasive

I need to import data from pervasive database to sql server. I have installed pervasive db claient & oledb provider. the pervasive database with me is in file format (folder with .DAT files). I would like to know how to read data from these files. when i used connection string as "Provider=PervasiveOLEDB;Data Source=C:\datafilesDirectory;" it gives unspecified error in 'Test Connection'. As i missing something here? Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have DDF files (FILE.DDF, FIELD.DDF, INDEX.DDF) that describe the data files?  Btrieve files do not store field information in them.  If you don't have DDF files, you will need them in order to use OLEBD (or ODBC or ADO.NET or any other relational method).

At the same time, you will need more than just the PSQL "Client".  You will need a PSQL engine available to read the files.  Did you install an engine (workgroup or server) or client?

Comment: What i have is one folder containing files with .DAT extension, FILE0001.DAT to FILE0207.DAT I was having client only, now i will install workgroup/server to see if it solves my issue. Btw why only the OLEDB driver would NOT be enough to read the files?

Comment: With the information you provided, it seems that you do not have DDF Files.  That being the case, the only way you can access the data is through Btrieve API calls.  If you have DDF files, you can use OLEDB, ODBC, or any of the other relational access methods PSQL offers.

Comment: thanks for all your info, this should help me moving forward !

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed were you able to access files ? I am in the same boat it seems